# variables from batch file to powershell

Tags: powershell

I get from an .exe generated batch file with variables in this format

```
$PATCODE = "000110"
$PATCIVILITE = "Mr"
$PATNOM = "DOE"
$PATPRENOM = "JOHN"
$PATSEXE = "MASCULIN"
$PATBIRTH = "19800104"
```

I have insert after these variables the .ps1 script

```
PowerShell -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\Users\\abc.ps1"" "%$PATCODE%" "%$PATCIVILITE%" "%$PATNOM%" "%$PATPRENOM%" "%$PATSEXE%" "%$PATBIRTH%""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

My ps1 script abc is

```
$pathExe = Set-Location “C:\Users\\”
$openExe = " C:\Users\\xyz.exe"
$PATCODE=$args[0]
$PATCIVILITE=$args[1]
$PATNOM=$args[2]
$PATPRENOM=$args[3]
$PATSEXE=$args[4]
$PATBIRTH=$args[5]
$pathExe
& $openExe -PatId="$PATCODE" -Title="$PATCIVILITE" -Lastname="$PATNOM" -Firstname="$PATPRENOM" -Sex="$PATSEXE" -Bithday="$PATBIRTH"
```

Unfortunately the variables are not passed from the batch file to the script.
Further I have to change the sex from "MASCULIN" to "M" and the birthday from  "19800101" to "1980-01-04".
I am going to despair on it.
Thank you for any help

Comment: What you call a batch file isn't one; it looks like a PowerShell script. From a `cmd.exe` prompt / a batch file, for a variable reference such as `%$PATCODE%` to work, the variable would have to be defined as `set $PATCODE=000110`

Comment: You are absolutely right - thank you. It works with **set $PATCODE=000110** and **%$PATCODE%**.